# Cannot render value to the html in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am implementing this code in my component that basically fetches data from a database. I can `console.log` the data and I can actually see the results and I can event `alert` it. But when I render it in my html, I do not see the value anymore. Please see my code below:

**.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.unitid = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('unitid');
    if (this.unitid === null) {
        this.router.navigate(['/main/viewproperties']);
    }
    this.getLessee();
    this.getLessor();
}

getLessor() {
    this.clientService.getUnitOwner(this.unitid)
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.unitLessor = data;
          console.log(data);
          this.fname = this.unitLessor.FirstName;
          alert(this.fname);
        });
}
```

**.html**

```
<div *ngIf="fname">
   {{fname}}
</div>
```

below is what I get on `console.log`

[image]

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: No I don't. As you can see from my image, I am actually able to get the result.

Comment: you'll have to import ``ChangeDetectorRef`` from core , and call ``.detectChanges()`` inside the subscription once ``fname`` is set .

Comment: Thank you for the ChangeDetectorRef. Somehow that worked. But I think I need to investigate it more since, I shouldn't be needing that anymore.

Comment: did you changed the change detection strategy of the component where you fetch that info?

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean. @Jota.Toledo

Comment: Normally, whenever you manually subscribe in a component, angular marks the component instance as dirty whenever the subscribed stream emits a value. This isnt the case when you set the `changeDetection` property of the `@Component` decorator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a change detection issue .

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private _cdr : ChangeDetectorRef){}


getLessor() {
    this.clientService.getUnitOwner(this.unitid)
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.unitLessor = data;
          console.log(data);
          this.fname = this.unitLessor.FirstName;
          alert(this.fname);
          this._cdr.detectChanges();
        });
}
```

Comment: @stackquestions no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use router param to initiate ngOnInit() once again if param value changes and it subscribe the value into HTML when param has value, you can try this way :

```
unitLessor: any; // declare model/entity here
ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      this.unitid = parseInt(params['unitid']);
      if (this.unitid) {
         this.getLessor(this.unitid); 
      }else{
          this.router.navigate(['/main/viewproperties']);
      }
      this.getLessee();
   }
 }

 getLessor(id: number) {
     this.clientService.getUnitOwner(id)
       .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.unitLessor = data;
        console.log(data);
     });
 }
```

AND Html could be :

```
   <div *ngIf="unitLessor">
       {{unitLessor.FirstName}}
   </div>
   OR
   <div *ngIf="unitLessor?.FirstName">
       {{unitLessor.FirstName}}
   </div>
```